# Increasing shards in Citus

Tags: citus

How can we add shards to existing colocated tables in citus?

I found out that the default is 32, which is definitely lower than expected. Is there a easy way of resizing without downtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alter_distributed_table` and supply `shard_count` param to update the total number of shards of a distributed table. It is a nice idea to apply this change to all the distributed tables in the colocation group so that you do not see any degraded performance on distributed table joins.

```sql
-- change shard count of all tables in colocation group
SELECT alter_distributed_table('github_events', shard_count:=6, cascade_to_colocated:=true);
```

See [Official Docs for Citus 10.2](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v10.2/develop/api_udf.html#alter-distributed-table)

### Downtime

There will be a small time frame where Citus will need to acquire an `ExclusiveLock` to change the shard count, where concurrent operations will not be able to access the relations in the colocation group.

If you are running a high workload on your Citus cluster, `alter_distributed_table` can be blocked while waiting for acquiring the necessary locks on tables.